# Change LibreOffice to certain size, even in fullscreen presentation

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, window-manager, libreoffice, devilspie

I want to open LibreOffice with keeping just a little bit of space left, already tried `wmctrl` without full-screen and that wasn't working to begin with.

I'd like to know if its able to stay the certain size I specified through [`devilspie2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=devilspie) or something else that can change the size, even if it goes into full-screen mode.

I'm using matchbox-window-manager on a Raspberry Pi 3.

It's working with OmxPlayer but still not with LibreOffice, I'm trying another window-manager out, any tips are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own half-answer:

I use `omxplayer video.mp4 --win "784 588 1024 748"`   to have it in a small window over another program

Now I just need to know how I can do it with LibreOffice during a fullscreen presentation..